# Hover menu on iPad (iOS 8) horizontal causes tap/click events in wrong elements

Tags: html, ios, css

I have a navigation menu that on a desktop browser uses a hover event that expands a collapsed menu. It works fine on Desktop.

The problem is that on the iPad it appears like the wrong menu item is tapped.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Put iPad in horizontal mode
2. Go to http://qaphppos.blastohosting.com/PHP-Point-Of-Sale/

   - username: admin
   - password: 12345678
3. Click Sales on the left side
4. Try to click any other item on the left side and you will see that your click doesn't translate to the right menu item.

Is this a bug in iOS 8 or is this something that I can even fix? I wouldn't mind if they had to tap twice (once to open menu and once to select); but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Chris, I cannot get access to your dashboard through Safari on iOS8. I've also tried to use the browser within Google Search app and everything looks to be working fine (access and behavior). May be a browser related issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are setting focus with JavaScript on the textbox labelled “enter item name or scan”. So your first tap is losing focus for the textbox, and the second actually select the menu.

After entering sales:

1. Try tapping on a black space. You will see the textbox lose focus.
2. Try tapping on the menu items, they will work.

Comment: Great catch! I will have to add a preference for iPad to disable focus

Comment: @ChrisMuench Could you tell me why you are making focus? I imagine that you automatically set focus to capture scanned codes?  If that’s the case, I may be able to provide a workaround.

Comment: That was the reason; but on the iPad don't I don't care as I don't integrate with a scanner. I have already made the fix based on your observations

Answer (score 0):

As Joe mentioned problem is in setting focus on the textbox labelled "enter item name or scan barcode".
But I wan't to mention that your textbox is not getting exact focus, it is looking like textbox is in focus but it's not, because if textbox is in full focus then device keypad should open automatically as soon as textbox gets focus.
I think css class for textbox focus is setting but textbox is not getting focus.